# How to send a SOAP request with Jest and Supertest?

Tags: soap, jestjs, supertest

What I need is to send a SOAP request, which is a XML file.

How I can send the content which is a XML file as a post request?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example:

`app.js`:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const xmlparser = require('express-xml-bodyparser');

app.use(xmlparser());
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  res.json(req.body);
});

module.exports = app;
```

`app.test.js`:

```js
const app = require('./app');
const request = require('supertest');

describe('57353993', () => {
  // read from XML file
  var itemsXML = '<list><item>item1</item><item>item2</item><item>item3</item></list>';
  var itemList = {
    list: {
      item: ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'],
    },
  };
  it('should pass', async () => {
    const res = await request(app)
      .post('/')
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/xml')
      .send(itemsXML);
    expect(res.status).toBe(200);
    expect(res.body).toEqual(itemList);
  });
});
```

Test result:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/57353993/app.test.js (9.465s)
  57353993
    ✓ should pass (56ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        10.598s, estimated 11s
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this:

```
const xml = "<note><to>Hello</to><from>World</from></note>"
const res = await request(app)
    .post('/')
    .set('Content-Type', 'application/xml')
    .send(xml);
```